How do I resolve extensions incompatibility in the notebook
I installed the nbextensions tab in my notebook but can't access the extensions. Instead I get a warning sign showing that they are incompatible despite being listed.
I tried downgrading to notebook 5.3.4 but still that didn't work.How do I resolve this issue.

What version of the software were using before you tried downgrading? How and roughly when did you install Jupyter? What extensions do you need? There's been a lot of change in Jupyter in the last year or so and nbextensions are generally not pertinent these days.
